# How to use Ajax each function with dynamic number of DIV tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

My code-igniter `mysql` `JSON` response contents bulk of email address. How should i add each `div` tags for each email address. Now display only last email address.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#option1').click(function() {
    $.ajax({
      url: '<?php echo base_url(); ?>' + 'main/studentdetails',
      dataType: "JSON",
      type: "POST",
      success: function(retdata) {
        $.each(retdata, function(i, item) { //i = number of records
          $(".target").html(retdata[i].email);
        });
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<body>
  <input type="button" id="option1">
  <div class='target'>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: `$(".target").append(item.email);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use **[`append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/)** instead of **[`html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/)**, otherwise it will replace the previous value and last value will be shown.

```
$(".target").append(item.email);
```